# Craft 3 Image Editor not Saving/Working

Tags: craft3

For some reason editing images isn't working for me. Specifically saving/replacing. Nothing happens.

The two errors I get in the console are;

```
POST http://dev.test/index.php?p=admin/actions/assets/save-image 500 (Internal Server Error)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of null
    at s.constructor.<anonymous> (Craft.js:5952)
    at Object.error (Craft.js:361)
    at c (jquery.js:3317)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.js:3447)
    at l (jquery.js:9274)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:9514)
```

Comment: You might want to show us the error message of the internal server error or at least your logs, otherwise there is little we can do

Comment: If the 500 Internal Server Error was generated by Craft, the underlying error message will be in your `craft/storage/logs` folder.  If it was generated by your web server, it'll be in your web server's error logs.